# Pausing a JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I'm currently working on an audio streaming application for iOS and I am new to swift. I am able to currently pull songs from the database using JSON serialization and then create buttons for every individual song and play them, but I cannot figure out how to pause them?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var songArray: [Array<String>] = []  //array to contain song names and filepaths

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //connect to website
        let url = URL(string:"http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team22/SongData.php")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("error")
            }
            else
            {
                if let content = data
                {
                    do
                    {
                        //download JSON data from php page, display data
                        let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [[String]]
                        print(JSON)

                        //Make buttons with JSON array
                        var buttonY:  CGFloat = 20
                        for song in JSON {
                            //add information to array
                            self.songArray.append(song)
                            let SongButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 250, height: 30))
                            buttonY = buttonY + 50 // 50px spacing

                            SongButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10  //Edge formatting for buttons

                            SongButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray //Color for buttons

                            SongButton.setTitle("\(song[0])", for: UIControlState.normal) //button title

                            SongButton.titleLabel?.text = "\(song[0])" // set title label

                            SongButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(self.songButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)  //button press / response

                            self.view.addSubview(SongButton)  // adds buttons to view
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        print(songArray)

    }


    func songButtonPressed(_ sender:UIButton!) { // Streaming function for buttons when pressed
        for song in songArray {
            if  "\(song[0])" == sender.titleLabel?.text { //compare loop element to name of button pressed



                let URL = NSURL(string: song[1])  //plug loop element into audio player
                let player = AVPlayer(url: URL! as URL)
                let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
                playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
                self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
                player.play()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with "Pausing a JSON array". This is to do with pausing some media.

Comment: Google "pause audio swift ios"

Answer (score 0):

Go to Apple docs and look up `AVPlayer`.  There is a `.pause()` function.  Simple as that.  Your other problem is that you don't have any way of accessing that player outside of your `songButtonPressed` scope, so you need to make a variable in your viewController (i.e. below your `var songArray...`, so that when somebody presses the pause button you can say `self.player.pause()`.

Link to docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer